# Manjaro: App appears to be unable to find library, but it is there

Tags: library

I am trying to launch a commercial app on my up to date Manjaro system. Apparently it is missing a library that this app needs (libtinfo.so.5). So I "installed" that library but I keep getting the same error.

The errors I get are all of this variety:

```
error: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the following:

1) I first created a path where the library lives, and added that to my shell that I launch from via the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/apps/studio/isotropix/clarisse/lib

ll /opt/apps/studio/isotropix/clarisse/lib
total 728
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov 21 17:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Dec 10 00:13 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Nov 21 17:51 libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  68076 Sep 28 06:43 libform.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Nov 21 17:51 libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  38592 Sep 28 06:43 libmenu.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Nov 21 17:51 libncurses++.so.5 -> libncurses++.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Nov 21 17:51 libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67668 Sep 28 06:43 libncurses++.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 166060 Sep 28 06:43 libncurses.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov 21 17:51 libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  17708 Sep 28 06:43 libpanel.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Nov 21 17:51 libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67296 Sep 28 06:43 libtic.so.5.9*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Nov 21 17:51 libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 295880 Dec 12 23:02 libtinfo.so.5.9*
```

But I still get the same errors.

I then added this library directly to my /usr/lib directory.

```
/usr/lib$ ls -l libtinfo.so.5*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Dec 13 12:16 libtinfo.so.5 -> /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 295880 Dec 13 12:15 libtinfo.so.5.9
```

But still the same errors.

So I tried enabling the debug to see where the app is searching and I get this (this just a sub-section of the output):

```
5351:   find library=libtinfo.so.5 [0]; searching
      5351:  search path=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64:/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib        (RPATH from file liboslcomp.so)
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/Desktop/3party/osl/install_dir/lib/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/oiio/install_dir/lib/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/home/kcam/jupiter/share/3rdparty_build/linux64/llvm-3.5.0.src/lib/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:  search path=tls/x86_64/x86_64:tls/x86_64:tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64/x86_64:x86_64:x86_64:       (RPATH from file /opt/apps/commercial/isotropix/clarisse/3.6sp6/clarisse.bin)
      5351:   trying file=tls/x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=tls/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=x86_64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=x86_64/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=libtinfo.so.5
      5351:  search path=/opt/apps/commercial/isotropix/clarisse/3.6sp6:/opt/apps/commercial/isotropix/clarisse/3.6sp6/python:/opt/apps/studio/isotropix/clarisse/lib       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5351:   trying file=/opt/apps/commercial/isotropix/clarisse/3.6sp6/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/opt/apps/commercial/isotropix/clarisse/3.6sp6/python/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:   trying file=/opt/apps/studio/isotropix/clarisse/lib/libtinfo.so.5
      5351:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5351:  search path=/usr/lib       (system search path)
      5351:   trying file=/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5
```

From this it looks like it is actually looking in both of those locations, but I can't tell if it is actually finding anything. Based on the fact that it does not stop searching even after it seems to check a valid path leads me to believe that something else is going on, but I have no idea what. Maybe it finds the file but rejects it because it is the wrong version?  But I would have expected a different error message then.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly did you "install" this library?

Comment: Just copied it to the various locations.  I.e. I made a copy in the path described by LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I also made a copy in /usr/lib/

Comment: OK, but where did you get it?

Comment: I googled the library and then downloaded it from here: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)   I downloaded the one listed as: Ncurses compatibility libraries Fedora Rawhide for aarch64 since the commercial app is supposed to be compatible with RedHat and CentOS.

Comment: Obviously a library for ARM won't run on Intel.

Comment: Wow. What a dumb mistake. :) I just downloaded the x86_64 rpm and installed that version's lib. It still breaks on other libraries, but they are giving me ELFCLASS32 errors - which means that I have downloaded the wrong versions of those as well. Thanks so much for taking the time. If you want to post your answer as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.